# Performing and simplifying equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The expression is $$\frac {5}{x-2} - \frac 3{x+7} + 2$$
>
> I need to simplify it too.

Comment: Could you put parentheses around numerators and denominators? That would help clarify what the fractions are. Do you mean $$\frac {5}{x-2} - \frac 3{x+7} + 2$$?

Comment: important nitpick to make: this is an _expression_, not an equation. Equations have equals signs in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac {5}{x-2} - \frac 3{x+7} + 2$$

Find the common denominator!

$$\begin{align}\frac {5}{x-2} - \frac 3{x+7} + 2 & = \dfrac{5(x+7)}{(x - 2)(x+ 7)} - \dfrac{3(x - 2)}{(x-2)(x+7)} + \frac{2(x-2)(x+7)}{(x-2)(x+7)} \\ \\& =\dfrac{5(x+7) - 3(x-2) + 2(x-2)(x+7)}{(x - 2)(x+7)} \\ \\ \end{align}$$

Now, expand the numerator, factor it if you can, cancel any like factors, i.e., simplify.

Comment: Feel free to check back to confirm/check-out what you get when you expand and simplify the numerator!

Comment: What I did was: 5x+35-3x+6 then I was not sure of the distribution of 2(x-2)(x+7) Should I only distribute 2 to (x-2)? @amWhy

Comment: You could do that: $2(x-2)(x+7) = (2x - 4)(x+7)$ and then expand. Or, you can first, multiply $(x - 2)(x+7) = x^2 + 5x - 14$. Then, multiply the expansion by $2$: $2(x - 2)(x+7) = 2(x^2 + 5x - 14) = 2x^2 + 10x - 28$. Either way, you'll get the same result.

Comment: my answer is 2x^2+12x+13/x^2+5x-14, should i still simplify it? @amWhy

Comment: Nope (no need to simplify further):  you've simplified correctly! Congratulations!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, if it's been helpful, @ikaidubidu $\large\checkmark$ ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Always showing the nice details! +1

Comment: @amWhy I agree with Amzoti so $\huge\color{blue}{+}^+$:)